# Variable within an instance of a class does not take a new value when it is assigned.

Tags: python, class, variables, undefined

So, I'm working on a command line RPG for the sake of filling time, and re-stretching my Python muscles as I've been out of practice for a couple of years. I used to code in a really functional manner but I'm trying to get my head around object-orientated programming.

Preamble aside, I have an issue where after creating an instance of a class, my class variable is no longer being defined. I've made 2 versions of this which I'll use to demonstrate since I'm finding it hard to articulate.

Below I created a "character" class which I intended to use as a basis for both player characters and npcs. In the first draft I was updating this class, before realising it was going to affect subclasses, when I really just wanted it as a template. Either way, this particular code block worked; it adds the values of 2 dictionaries together, then assigns them to `character.characterStats`. It then prints them as per `displayStats()`.

```
from collections import Counter

class character:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        pass

    characterRace = ''
    characterStats = {}
    charLocation = ''
    charName = ''

class race:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    baseStatsDict = {
        'Strength' : 5,
        'Agility' : 5,
        'Toughness' : 5,
        'Intelligence' : 5 }

    humanStatsDict = {
        'Strength' : 1,
        'Agility' : 1,
        'Toughness' : 1,
        'Intelligence' : 1 }


def displayRace():
    print("Race: ", character.characterRace, "\n")

def displayStats():
    for stat, value in character.characterStats.items():
        print(stat, "=", value)
    print("\n")

def raceSelection():
    playerInput = input("I am a ")
    playerInput
    playerLower = playerInput.lower()

    while "human" not in playerLower:
        if "human" in playerLower:
            character.characterStats = dict(Counter(race.baseStatsDict)+Counter(race.humanStatsDict))
            character.characterRace = 'Human'
            break

        playerInput = input()
        playerInput
        playerLower = playerInput.lower()


playerChar = character()
raceSelection()
displayRace()
displayStats()
```

And this was the output:

```
Race:  Human 

Strength = 6
Agility = 6
Toughness = 6
Intelligence = 6
```

This however is the new code when I tried to tidy it up and turn the class into the template it was meant to be, and started using the class instance `playerChar` which for whatever reason can't assign the new value to `playerChar.characterStats`. `playerChar.displayStats()` prints the `characterRace` and `characterStats` variables as empty, even though they are assigned when the player enters the value `human`.

```
from collections import Counter

class character:
    characterRace = ''
    characterStats = {}

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def displayRace(self):
        print("Race: ", self.characterRace, "\n")

    def displayStats(self):
        for stat, value in self.characterStats.items():
            print(stat, "=", value)
        print("\n")

class race:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    baseStatsDict = {
        'Strength' : 5,
        'Agility' : 5,
        'Toughness' : 5,
        'Intelligence' : 5 }

    humanStatsDict = {
        'Strength' : 1,
        'Agility' : 1,
        'Toughness' : 1,
        'Intelligence' : 1 }

def raceSelection():
    playerInput = input("I am a ")
    playerInput
    playerLower = playerInput.lower()

    while "human" not in playerLower:
        if "human" in playerLower:
            playerChar.characterStats = dict(Counter(race.baseStatsDict)+Counter(race.humanStatsDict))
            playerChar.characterRace = 'Human'
            break

        playerInput = input()
        playerInput
        playerLower = playerInput.lower()

playerChar = character()
raceSelection()
playerChar.displayRace()
playerChar.displayStats()
```

So this will output:

```
Race:
\n
\n
\n
```

So I know it's able to draw from the `class race` dictionaries and add their contents together as from the previous code. If I try and print the `player.x` characteristics it won't throw any errors so it recognises they exist. If anyone could explain to me what's going wrong and why in this new iteration, I'd be very grateful.

EDIT: So a friend and I have tried passing the class as an argument of `raceSelection()`, we've tried printing a string after each call/update of a variable and we've tried entering a string into the variable, printing it, then redefining the variable with a new string.

Input:

```
class character:
    charRace = ''
    charStats = {}
    charLocation = ''
    charName = ''
    charString = "Cole said define a string."
```

Within the `if` statements:

```
if "human" in playerLower:
    print("Oh, you're just a really ugly human.")
    playerChar.charStats = dict(Counter(race.baseStatsDict)+Counter(race.humanStatsDict))
    playerChar.charRace = 'Ugly Human'
    print("playerChar.charString = ", playerChar.charString)
    playerChar.charString = "Redefine."
    print("playerChar.charString = ", playerChar.charString)
    break
```

Output:

```
Oh, you're just a really ugly human.
playerChar.charString =  Cole said define a string.
playerChar.charString =  Cole said define a string.
Race:
```

Comment: I don't think     while "human" or "elf" or "orc" not in playerLower:
has the behaviour you want, it is doing if 'human' (which is true) or 'elf' (which is true) or 'orc' not in playerLower (which is the only one you want to check)

Comment: Oops, sorry, I stripped out the residual stuff for the purposes of illustration, I have code blocks for all 3 options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying to move the variables in and out of `__init__`, trying `setattr()`, trying to pass any sort of argument through the class just so it had some data, trying to run the instance of the class through a function, none of those solutions came to work in the end.

The solution turned out to be to create a subclass of `character` and manipulate that instead. I figured this would be alright as well since the player character will mutate throughout gameplay, and will never see further subclasses of itself.

Answer (score 0):

It *should not* be `character.characterStats.items()`, but  `self.characterStats.items()`. Similarly for all other values that belong to *one, specific* character.

Using the name of the class assigns a value that belongs to the class, and is the same for all objects you create. Lookup *instance vs class attributes*.

Comment: You'll notice that in the second set of code I have used `self.characterStats.items()`, that's why I'm confused that the variable isn't taking the value.